# Android M weird shared preferences issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-6.0-marshmallow

On my Nexus 5 running Android M Developer Preview 2, when uninstalling/reinstalling an app, the device is retrieving shared preferences I stored long ago, for instance a boolean `isFirstLaunch`.

The only way to clear these is to do it manually from the device settings.

Is there any change in shared preferences behavior on Android M? I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Or maybe the Android M Preview 2 ROM has a bug...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

That is because Android M will feature [Automatic Backups](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) ([old](https://developer.android.com/preview/backup/index.html) link).

Extract:

> The automatic backup feature preserves the data your app creates on a
>   user device by uploading it to the user’s Google Drive account and
>   encrypting it. There is no charge to you or the user for data storage
>   and the saved data does not count towards the user's personal Drive
>   quota. During the M Preview period, users can store up to 25MB per
>   Android app.

Comment: Google rotted the link, I think it can be found here now: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Answer (score 14):

Even already answered this question above, not mentioned the actual solution to avoid the auto backup even after uninstalling the app.

As per official, [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#EnablingAutoBackup) says to avoid auto backup need to do `<application android:allowBackup="false">` in the Manifest file under application tag.:

> Enabling and disabling backup
> Apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher automatically participate in Auto Backup because of the `android:allowBackup` attribute defaults to true. To avoid any confusion, you should explicitly set the attribute in your manifest as follows:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> You might **want to disable backups by setting this to false** if your app can recreate its state through some other mechanism or when your app deals with sensitive information that should not be backed up

Answer (score 8):

Open settings -> Backup & reset -> automatic restore -> off
if is on then app cache and database will be restore.