# SharedPreferences not being removed on user uninstalling application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, nexus-6p

Has anyone encountered this issue on a Nexus 6P device? I am only getting this issue on a Nexus 6P (running Google Fi).

When I install the app there is a key for `userIsLoggedIn` inside `SharedPreferences`.

This block:

```
boolean userIsLoggedIn  = SharedPrefs.userIsLoggedIn(this);

// Then in another class...

 public static boolean userIsLoggedIn(Context context) {
    // For users updating apps, if the previous key-value is a string, convert it to boolean
    try {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean(USER_LOGGED_IN, false);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putBoolean(USER_LOGGED_IN, false)
                .commit();
        return context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean(USER_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }
}
```

Now this should return `false` on a new uninstall but debugging this on a fresh install I get the following on App Startup.

[image]

I also running Proguard if that matters, when running the device on a non-proguard enabled APK it runs ok. Running proguard on any other devices runs fine.

Comment: Have you checked with any other devices? Code seems fine.

Comment: I think login is true somewhere in code because shared preference dont behave like that so please check that first.

Comment: That is definitely not the issue, this piece of code is run first. Have confirmed on 8 other devices.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Since Nexus 6P is running Android M, I think [Automatic Backups](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) is the issue.

I think You can use [allowBackup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup) to stop that.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010582/336312

Answer (score 21):

In android M and above versions they keep application backups in google driver, you can disable this by using,
go to your project **manifest** file under **Application** section set `android:allowBackup="true"` to false.and you are good to go.

Answer (score 18):

you can add to your manifest:

```
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
```