# Android Shared Preference , Issues with Version 6

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am been working on App and I prefer storing few details likes Tokens,Id's in Shared Preference. Ideally if App gets Uninstalled then all data in the  Shared Preferences should be removed.

A strange issues noted with new versions of Android after reinstalling the App I can able to see all stored values , I am sure  am debugging after  Uninstalling the last version.

Any suggestion on this behaviour ? 
 Thanks,

Comment: You first uninstalled the app, then installed a new one correct? Not reinstall in one go?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010538/android-m-weird-shared-preferences-issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes it is happen because your app is not properly uninstalled. this happen to me with android 6.1 
**firsly go to app and on right top there is button to change user. then uninstall your app for all user. then it will work**