# Erasing shared preferences upon uninstall

Tags: android, local-storage, sharedpreferences

I have a weird bug in my app. It only happens, from what I see , in newer devices.
When I uninstall the app, and the install it again, I noticed that certain keys are preserved in sharedpreferences, even if they were removed before.

```
For example :
 1. User "abc" is logged in. 
 2. He logs out(his id is then erased from sharedpreferences by setting empty string value in the id key). 
 3. uninstalls the app
 4. installs it again
 5. on launching the app the "id" key exists in the shared preferences.
```

But it doesn't happen on all devices , so I guess it can be related to certain Android os versions..

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010538/android-m-weird-shared-preferences-issue/32010582#32010582

Comment: When I try to change `allowBackup` to `false`, I get an error `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: @NeriaNachum I also tried removing the allowBackup line completely, but it didn't help.
while setting it to false gives me the aforementioned error

Comment: There are a few questions about this issue as well. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39509659/5280641

Comment: @NeriaNachum Unfortunately it didn't help.. :/