# SharedPreferences still there after uninstall

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm getting some weird behavior lately. It seems my share prefs are not getting deleted upon uninstall. When I reinstall my app after an uninstall, the shared prefs file still has the values from the previous install. This is very weird, I know. The only thing that blows away my shared prefs is using "Clear Data" in the settings app.

I've tried uninstalled both ways: by clicking uninstall in Settings and also `adb uninstall`.

Steps:

1. Uninstall my app from the Settings app.
2. run `adb uninstall <package>` for good measure.
3. Install app again by launching it in debug mode.
4. Hit initial breakpoint: shared prefs are still there.

I made sure my app isn't setting setting the prefs before it hits the breakpoint.

Note: My debug version is signed so I can test upgrades from the Google Play release version. *However this problem happens on clean installs.*

**I'm running Oreo (8.1.0).**

Has anyone else seen this very strange behavior?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010538

Comment: I notice that you edited only to specify the version you're running. I would point out that Automatic Backups were _introduced_ in Marshmallow. They're not specific to that version. Do you mean to say that Automatic Backups is not your issue? Did you test by setting `allowBackup` to `false` on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: Yes the issue was backups. Thank you.